# SSL: Hosting a Webservice automatically at the right domain name

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, ssl, hostname

**This is my scenario:**
I have a self hosted web service that may be started on several different hosts. Some, not yet defined, load balancing will direct to the right one. 
I also got a configuration, that assigns ssl-certificates (thumbprints) to each host.
Dependent on which machine the service is started, it will take the corresponding certificate, and bind it to its port. As URL for the Service, it reads the 'issued to' from the certificate, so that I don't get a name mismatch on the client.
For my self-signed certificates, this works as expected.

**Problem**
I found out, that there are multi-domain certificates available, so that the 'isseud to' part will only contain the primary URL. So I guess, my current implementation will not work in this scenario.

Is there any best practice, to get my code working in any possible scenario? Should I go with the full qualified hostname? Or is there no generic way to handle that? Do I need to let people configure the URL of the Webservice for every possible host?

**UPDATE**
I want to extend the question by a related one, that may help me understand the topic:

When I host a self hosted webservice on a machine, does it make sense to host it with a different address then the one of the machine?
So let's assume my machines qualified hostname is mymachine.bla.com.
Then I would host the service with http(s)://mymachine.bla.com:8080/blub.
Is there any good reason, to host the service at
http(s)://sometotalydifferentadress:8080/blub. 
Is there any scenario, where it makes sense to do something like that? If so, can you give me an example? Or should it always be the hostname?

Comment: Is your service going to run on all webservers behind the Load balancer?

Comment: That's not yet decided. There may be situations with a direct connection.

Comment: I updated the question, added a new question that might help me

Comment: What authentication mechanism does your service have?  Also its not a good practice to use self signed certificates in production.